# Unity OnMouseDown too slow

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface

I am coding a clicker game and I do not want my program to calculate whenever I press the UI. I have tried using OnMouseDown, OnPointerDown and !EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject() but all of them ruin the clicker-feel because you can't spam click. Are there any shorter alternatives? Thank you in advance!

Edit: I've done all the things you've commented and I've found the problem. Whenever I click my mouse button, text appears with the number of coins I get per tap. Therefore, it counts as a UI element, making it not possible to spam-click. I have now turned off the "Raycast Target" for the text and now it works as it should. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Input.GetButtonDown() in fixedupdate

Comment: @John 's answer is probably best. 
Other ideas: Maybe you should keep track of each objects "last clicked time", and define an alternative, lighter, behaviour for such cases? Also consider openning coroutines in each click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Input class along with a check:

```
void Update()
    {
        // Check if the left mouse button was clicked
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            // Check if the mouse was clicked over a UI element
            if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
            {
                Debug.Log("Clicked on the UI");
            }
        }
    }
```

Or you can use OnMouseDown on specific object where you want to detect the click but with a UI check:
void OnMouseDown()
{

```
        // Check if the mouse was clicked over a UI element
        if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
        {
            Debug.Log("Clicked on the UI");
        }
   
}
```